# Binary Tree In Order creation using Arithmetic Expression Queue

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes, arithmetic-expressions, inorder

I'm trying to implement code that takes a queue, titled 'input,' that has an arithmetic expression.
The expression looks like this:

```
5 - a * 6 + b
```

This expression is stored into a queue and I have a method that checks the type of whatever I'm popping in my queue.  The method is called getIt() and it returns an integer that tells if it is either an operand or operator.  1 is equal to an operand; 0 is equal to operator.  So if I call queue.pop() which should return the value pop the value '5', the getIt() method call on that pop would return 1.

I have an add method that takes in a queue and is supposed to add the values of the queue into a binary tree using the in order system.

```
BinNode<Term> current = new BinNode<>();
BinNode<Term> parent = new BinNode<>();

current = null;
parent = null;

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if (input.pop().getType() == 1) {
        current = new BinNode<Term>(input.pop());
    } else if (input.pop().getType() == 0) {
        parent = new BinNode<Term>(input.pop());
        parent.setLeft(current);
    }
}
```

In this code, I create two nodes called current/parent.  I created a loop that would iterate through the queue, check to see if a popped value would be an operand-- if yes, then I set the current node to that popped value.  If it's an operator, I set that to the parent node and set the left node to current.  My issue here is how I finish the tree.  If the goal of the tree is to make it appear similar to

```
               *
              / \
             -   +
            / \  / \
           5  a 6   b
```

I dont know how I can get my code to reflect this.

Comment: What is the tree that you get for the given expression (5 - a * 6 + b)?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question- my current code is pretty incomplete because I don't really know where to advance from here.  I posted a tree of what the goal is (like what im trying to do with the code) which is supposed to be an inorder add method.

Comment: I would like to suggest that you google "binary expression tree." There should be many examples.